# ClassLoader.class "source not found" error when instantiating a database class in android

Tags: android, database, classloader

I am trying to implement Content Providers and Cursor Loaders to get away from cursors as recommended by Android/Google. However, I'm having a terrible time of it. I'm using the tutorials at http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/android/android-sdk_content-providers/ as my guide and the simplest thing just isn't working. At the beginning of my Activity, I'm doing the following:

```
SQLData entry = new SQLData(getApplicationContext());
```

I've also tried

```
SQLData entry = new SQLData(this);
```

SQLData is the name of my database class. What I'd like to do after this line of code is create and populate the database using the methods from the content provider class I've created. However, when I try to move past this line in the debugger, a ClassLoader.class window opens, with the message "source not found". I've reloaded and refreshed and cleaned my package, but this doesn't help.  I'm happy to provide all the code for my database and content provider classes, but I'm not sure that's what's needed here. Does anyone know how to approach this issue?

Thanks very much!

Comment: Step over rather than step into.  I assume you are using Eclipse.  It's trying to step into the class loader which is going to load SQLData.  Since you don't have the Android source code referenced, it reports "source not found".  It might be fixable with an option, I use IDEA so don't know.  Anyway, step over will avoid it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm very comfortable debugging C#.Net code in VisualStudio, but I have to say that debugging in Eclipse is a bit of an uphill battle for me. I have no doubt I'll have more questions about switching to content providers and cursor loaders, but that's another question for another day.

Comment: You're welcome.  If you're learning, it might not be too late to switch to Intellij IDEA.  I too came from VS and find IDEA very much better than Eclipse, especially for debugging but the world of Java/Android is far removed from .net/Windows.  Have fun!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In android, or any java dev; you may find it more useful to write JUnit tests and put lots of

```
 Log.v(TAG, "message about " + variable);
```

in your code instead of using the debugger...

I write Java code as my job and use the debug option maybe twice a year as a last resort...

the JUnit tests get my errors out and save me TONS of time, stepping through code in the debugger can be a very time consuming thing...
just a tip, and it may just be my personal pref...